# ContentSearchManager does not return any Results

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Sitecore 8 ContentSearchManager does not return any result. Below is my code:

```
    public IQueryable<SearchResultItem> PerformSearch()
    {
        var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
        using (var searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var locations = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
            .Where(i => i.Path.StartsWith("/sitecore/content/GlobalReferences/Locations"));


            var item = locations.ToList();


            return locations;
        }
    }
```

Code Snapshot:

[image]

Sitecore Tree:

[image]

Is there anything that I need to do to make it work? Like setting up anything in config or something?

What I have tried so far:

- Rebuild Index [No Results]

Note:

I am using lucene.

**UPDATES:**

When I switch to master the records retrieves.

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
```

**UPDATES 2 (09/08/2015)**

Looks like I have a problem when performing indexing in web.

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_web_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Lucene.Net.Index.CorruptIndexException: checksum mismatch in segments file
   at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.Read(Directory directory, String segmentFileName)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexFileDeleter..ctor(Directory directory, IndexDeletionPolicy policy, SegmentInfos segmentInfos, StreamWriter infoStream, DocumentsWriter docWriter, HashSet`1 synced)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Init(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, Int32 maxFieldLength, IndexingChain indexingChain, IndexCommit commit)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter..ctor(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, MaxFieldLength mfl)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Sharding.LuceneShard.Reset()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.DoReset(IProviderUpdateContext context)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.PerformRebuild(IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.Rebuild()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Any ideas how to fix? What I have tried so far are:

- Rebuild Index
- Rebuild Tree
- Rebuild All

But nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to clean up the indexing of web so I could index from start?

**SOLUTION:**

Since the index is corrupted. I deleted the files and folders inside the \Data\indexes. Then after rebuild everything seems to work properly.

I also found [this](https://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/troubleshooting-sitecore-lucene-search-and-indexing/#.Ve1Z4BGeDGc). It helps also.

Comment: Do you use Lucene or Solr? Try to use lowercase path in your query `"/sitecore/content/globalreferences/locations"`

Comment: Can you switch to web database and check that "Locations" item and it's sub items are there?

Comment: @Ahmed, already checked. It is there (items and subitems)

Comment: Looks like there is an error while performing indexing in web. Please see update questions.

Comment: Ok, try to delete the whole index folder for web, then try again to rebuild it.

Comment: @Pinoy2015 You can find the index folder in "\Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index", You just need to delete that, then rebuild your index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Since the index is corrupted. I deleted the files and folders inside the \Data\indexes. Then after rebuild everything seems to work properly.

Comment: Glad that was the solution, Btw, You can Tick your answer as correct .

Answer (score 2):

Double check in your config for sitecore_web_index that the root path for the index is set so that it will include the globalreferences path.

There should a patch file for this in the include directory.

For reference it should be setup like this:

http://www.mikkelhm.dk/blog/defining-a-custom-index-in-sitecore-7-the-absolute-minimum

If you still can't get any data I would recommend downloading Luke to see exactly what's in your index

https://code.google.com/p/luke/

Comment: This is the root: <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>

Comment: As Marek asked are you using Lucene?

Comment: Yup, i am using lucen

Comment: If am not using a patch file and only using the default, does it not work without patch file?

Comment: It will work if directly out in the config, but a patch file might be overriding the settings. Have you done a /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to check if the root setting for the crawler is not being overridden?

Answer (score 0):

The answer below AND are you 100% sure that the items you search for are published? I know it's stupid, but sometimes we just seem to forget to publish.

Comment: Yup, after I rebuild index. I published it to make sure.